# In vue-electron, how to do you bind data between a parent and child components?

Tags: reactjs, vue.js, electron-vue

I am trying to learn electron-vue by understanding a finished code.
For the source, I am using Eplee, which is an epub reader built with vue js + electron 
Here is the source link to Eplee.
https://github.com/Janglee123/eplee

```
<!-- BookmarkMenu.vue -->

<template>
    <el-popover :popper-class="`popper ${theme}`" width="350" trigger="hover">
        <div class="el-popover__title">
            Bookmarks
            <el-button size="mini" icon="el-icon-plus" circle @click="addBookmark" />
        </div>
        <el-button slot="reference" size="small" icon="el-icon-collection-tag" circle />
        <el-tree :data="bookmarks" node-key="id" @node-click="onNodeClick">
            <span slot-scope="{ node }" class="custom-tree-node">
                <span>{{ node.label }}</span>
                <span>
                    <el-button type="text" icon="el-icon-close" @click="() => removeBookmark(node)" />
                </span>
            </span>
        </el-tree>
    </el-popover>
</template>

<script>
export default {
    name: 'BookmarkMenu',
    props:{
        bookmarks:{
            default:()=>{},
            type: Array,
        },
        theme:{
            default:'default',
            type:String,
        }
    },
    methods:{
        addBookmark(){
            this.$emit('add-bookmark');
        },
        removeBookmark(data){
            this.$emit('remove-bookmark',data);
        },
        onNodeClick(data){
            this.$emit('node-click',data);
        }
    }
}
</script>

<style lang="scss" scoped>

</style>
```

I do not understand how data is binded here.

For example,
`<el-button size="mini" icon="el-icon-plus" circle @click="addBookmark" />`
when there is a click

1. it triggers `addBookmark` method of BookmarkMenu.vue
2. `addBookmark` Method triggers `'add-bookmark'` of the parent component

But, `<el-button></el-button>` is just a class added for the purpose of styling, not a parent component.

For both vue and react, I thought in order to import components from a different file and properly place them I need to place two things.

1. import line
2. placement line

Question 1:
Is this a proper way to import? or do you only need 1. import line?

Question 2:
So, in vue-electron, how to do you bind data between a parent and child components?

What I am assuming is the file structor take cares of it
https://github.com/SimulatedGREG/electron-vue/blob/master/docs/en/renderer-process.md

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Electron is just a runtime for your web app.

Take a look at Vue.js's event model.

https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/events.html
https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-custom-events.html

Also, check out component guide https://ru.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html

In your case

> `<el-button></el-button>` is just a class added for the purpose of styling, not a parent component.

It is not a parent component it is a child component of `<BookmarkMenu>` component. And it may contain absolutely anything inside.

And `this.$emit('add-bookmark');` method triggers an event listener (if any) of a component which would have `<BookmarkMenu>` as a child.

For example `<BookmarkMenu @add-bookmark="someHandlerInAComponentContainingBookmarkMenu"/>`

Comment: hey, you are right. that's why I am confused. There isn't anything like `<BookmarkMenu></BookmarkMenu>` if you take a look into the source code. https://github.com/Janglee123/eplee

Comment: There is - https://github.com/Janglee123/eplee/blob/master/src/renderer/views/Reader.vue#L11

Comment: Klochko I see my mistake. childComponent="parentComponent", not "parentComponent" =  childComponent  and Vue does not require me to wrap with parentsComponent like <ParentsComponent> </ParentsComponent>Thanks!